# Vue.js can template without no root element or vue el specify for two div

Tags: vue.js

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
   Some HTML ...
</div>
<div class="b">
   Some HTML
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#item_info",
    ....
    ....
    (Other Config)
    ....
    ....
})
```

The two div above need to show the information from vue,

I tried using `<template></template>` like:

```
<template>
   (my two div)
</template>
```

but it does not work because both divs need to be inside a root element.

I know that if I modify my html to:

```
<div id="item_info">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

It can work, but I have no authorization to modify the base Html structure

Is there any other way that could help me solve it?

Comment: If you cannot modify the HTML, then how exactly do you expect to add a `<template>` tag around it?!

Comment: Can you give more details on *show the information from vue*?

Comment: @poke Oh, I did not describe it clearly, what i want to say is that if i add a div out of two divs, the css styles structure will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to split those div's in two components and then add them to parent.

One.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="a">
       Some HTML ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Two.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="b">
       Some HTML
    </div>
</template>
```

Three.vue

```
<template>
    <One></One>
    <Two></Two>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no authorization then I think you can't put that `<template></template>` either. Vue JS doesn't allow selecting multiple elements. But you can use Vue Component, please refer to this official link of Vue JS: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html.

But remember Component also requires one root element.